# Making phone beacon with dart/flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, altbeacon

I am trying to make a phone a beacon, i would like to know if flutter has a library i can use to transform mobile phone into beacon, 
The only library i found is the one that can range and detect a beacon though am interested in making a mobile phone a beacon,
https://pub.dev/packages/beacons#-example-tab-